# ClickOnce "Could not find required file...Engine\Launcher.exe" Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.2.4

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, clickonce

I'm publishing an internal application written in WPF and using Dotnet 5 to a shared network folder using ClickOnce using Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.2.4.

I've had no issues publishing this particular application in the past (I even pushed an update to the application earlier today).

When I attempt to publish I receive the error.

`1>Could not find required file 'C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\Engine\Launcher.exe'.`

I've removed the application name and my user name but outside of that this is the exact wording on the error.

Building the application for release and debug both work.

Attempting to publish to a different installation location does not fix the issue. I've deleted the bin and obj folder and forced a fresh build, still will not publish.

Switching to a different application and attempting to publish via ClickOnce I get the same error.

Restarting Visual Studio or restarting the computer has not fixed the issue.

I'm at a loss for how to fix this.

**Edit:
I've fixed this by upgrading to VS 17.3.4 and this seems to have fixed the issue. I have no idea what the problem was.**